# Change div content completely programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div which contains a few buttons (for log in).
After user is logged in using Facebook and redirected back to the page, I would like to keep this same div in there, but replace all its content with a new content. (remove buttons and say hi).

Since I am new I wonder what would be a good practice :

1. Create another `div` **inside the first**, set it to be hidden then when needed hide the first and show the other
2. Create another `div` **outside**, and do the same as 1.
3. a better way ?

Doing 1 or 2 - *I don't want the hidden div to take space when its hidden.*

How would you hide/show a `div` using Javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hidden `divs` will not take space of the page!

Addressing your points:

1. This will not work, just think logically: you hide the parent `div` (first `div` in your description), then **its children will also be hidden!**
2. This would be the way to do it! Just keep your 2 `divs` at the same level and hide/show them alternatly.
3. You can also just use 1 `div` and just replace its content for each use (being a better option highly depends on your context)

To make something like that in javascript, you could go along the lines:

```js
function switchdivs() {
  if (document.getElementById('one').style.display == 'block') {
    document.getElementById('one').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('one').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('two').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function replacediv() {
  if (document.getElementById('replacer').innerHTML == "Original content")
    document.getElementById('replacer').innerHTML = 'Replaced content';
  else
    document.getElementById('replacer').innerHTML = "Original content";
}
```

```css
#two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id='one'>
  one
</div>
<div id='two'>
  two
</div>
<button onclick="switchdivs()">Toggle the divs!</button>
<button onclick="replacediv()">Replace the div bellow!</button>
<div id='replacer'>
  Original content
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not necessary to create another div

You can change the content with innerHTML or innerText, if there is only text into the new content use innerText.

Like :

```js
document.getElementById('div').innerText = "Logged";
document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = "Bar<br/><b>Foo</b><button>Btn</button>";
```

```html
<div id="div">Login</div>
<div id="div2">Login</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, and what if its not only a text ? I would like to remove the buttons, put a text, and another button, I actually want a full pre built div that looks different.

Comment: use innerHTML instead, I updated my post to see an example

Answer (score 2):

```js
x = document.getElementById("my_div_id");   //Get div by ID
x.style.display = "none";                   //Hide
x.style.display = "block";                  //Show
```

```html
<div id="my_div_id">TEST DIV</div>
```

Your div have to be in this format `<div id="my_div_id">VALUE</div>`

More information here : [W3School Toggle](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you will know what you have been redirected, but lets assume this to `redirected` variable, if `redirected` is true, the div with buttons will be hidden, and other div - visible. If you provide some better use case Ill update my answer.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="buttons-container">
    <button>one</button>
    <button>two</button>
  </div>
  <div style="display: none" id="willShow">Hi</div>
</div>
```

---

```
const wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');
const willShow = document.getElementById('willShow');
const buttonsContainer = document.getElementById('buttons-container');

const redirected = true;
if(redirected) {
  buttonsContainer.style.display = 'none';
  willShow.style.display = 'block';
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RdEgQj